# Microsoft Graph V1 API error: OData::ServerError 503 ConcurrentItemSave: "Conflicts occurred during saving data to store

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, office365, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I'm having trouble debugging the issue occurs when pushing new events to Outlook Calendar using Microsoft Graph API (v1). I have tested and it's still working, but I received this error which happened a few times today from my Ruby on Rails apps with the gems mentioned in the code snippet below. And there are duplicate events added to the calendar after these errors. I have searched this issue but still got nothing. Could anyone help me to debug this problem, please? I just don't know if this issue caused by my users' actions or just API server error. Many thanks!

OData::ServerError 503 ConcurrentItemSave: "Conflicts occurred during saving data to store (saveresult: IrresolvableConflict, properties: ). Please retry the request." from "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/AAMkADg1YmMzNjE2LTM5Y2MtNGI2NC05NjJjLWRiY2RhZTZkNDRkMABGAAAAAADZc5aq6QclSqy_4oRMVv_EBwB4ZnW6S6xLTZDSXIsgJfprAAAAAAEGAAB4ZnW6S6xLTZDSXIsgJfprAAAGEcjmAAA=/events"

Code I use to create events via api

```
require 'adal'
require 'microsoft_graph'

username      = ENV["OUTLOOK_USERNAME"]
password      = ENV["OUTLOOK_PASSWORD"]
client_id     = ENV["OUTLOOK_CLIENT_ID"]
client_secret = ENV["OUTLOOK_CLIENT_SECRET"]
tenant        = ENV["OUTLOOK_TENANT"]
user_cred     = ADAL::UserCredential.new(username, password)
client_cred   = ADAL::ClientCredential.new(client_id, client_secret)
context       = ADAL::AuthenticationContext.new(ADAL::Authority::WORLD_WIDE_AUTHORITY, tenant)
resource      = "https://graph.microsoft.com/"
tokens        = context.acquire_token_for_user(resource, client_cred, user_cred)

callback = Proc.new { |r|
  r.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer #{tokens.access_token}"
  r.headers["Prefer"] = 'outlook.timezone="Australia/Sydney"'
  r.headers['Content-type'] = 'application/json'
}

@graph = MicrosoftGraph.new(
  base_url: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
  cached_metadata_file: File.join(MicrosoftGraph::CACHED_METADATA_DIRECTORY, "metadata_v1.0.xml"),
  &callback
)

#example_data
calendar_id = "my_calendar_id"
data = my_event_object

@graph.service.post("me/calendars/#{calendar_id}/events", data.to_json)
```

Comment: Could you please provide more information about the request body. I have tried this, and it works

Comment: @kikang yes, it's working most of the time. But yesterday my app on my user side ran into that error causing duplicate events created. I cannot reproduce the issue as well. I don't know if the API auto retry after this error occurs. Thank you!

Comment: Did you retry it?Is it work?

Comment: @KeenJin it happened again today. The error _OData::ServerError 503 ConcurrentItemSave_ is thrown at the last line in the code above (when an event is being created). I'm not sure if the issue comes from me using shared calendar. Do you know where I can find the document about the API errors? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's a GitHub issue opened for this problem: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-ruby/issues/38

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue. That's actually a problem on MS side and the reason was that the event object contained open extensions, which should be fine according to the documentation but practically causes a failure each 20-30 requests.

I fixed it by splitting the event creation request into two API calls. First request doesn't contain any extensions info attached to the event, and the 2nd request adds the extension data to the newly created event as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-open-users?tabs=http#request).

Now, this 2nd POST to `/extensions` may fail with the same error but i've wrapped it with the retry policy and according to my recent experience it doesn't require more than 1 retry to finish the job.